How to determine if a solution exists for a system of two modular linear diophantine equations
The problem is to solve for $x$ and $y$: $x+2y\equiv 3 \pmod {10}$ and $3x+y\equiv 2 \pmod {10}$. I solved for the same equations modulus 9, using a matrix and row operations. But modulus 10, I don't seem to be getting a solution. Should I first look at these equations as linear congruences and determine if the congruences have solutions?
For instance: $x+2y\equiv 3\pmod {10}$ implies $x\equiv 3\pmod {2}$ and $2y\equiv 3\pmod {1}$. (Does a modulus 1 congruence even make sense?) For linear congruences $ax\equiv b\pmod {m}$, a solution exists if $gcd(a, m)|b$. For both of these congruences, the greatest common divisor is 1, so they should have solutions. For $3x+y\equiv 2\pmod {10}$, the congruences are $3x\equiv 2\pmod {1}$ and $y\equiv 3\pmod {3}$.
I would say that this doesn't help. This leads me to believe that I am looking at this from the wrong perspective.
By the way, here is what happened when I tried to solve this with matrix algebra (please forgive my awkward notation):
$\pmod {10}:\ \left[\begin{matrix}1&2&3\\3&1&2\\\end{matrix}\right]{\frac {R2\gets 3R1-R2}{\rightarrow}}\left[\begin{matrix}1&2&3\\0&5&7\\\end{matrix}\right]$

If you subtract the second congruence from three times the first you get $5y\equiv 7\pmod {10}$ but that's impossible (as it would imply that $5,|,7$).

do mod 2  and mod 5 separately

@lulu: that was my point. I reached that and realized it didn't have a solution.

@willjagy, can you point me to a method to do that? When I tried to split each equation into two congruences, the result is two congruences with mod 1, which I don't think makes sense. If I had the congruences, I could use a version the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Not sure I see the question. The determinant of the associated $2\times 2$ matrix is $5$ (or $-5$).  That's obviously a problem $\pmod {10}$.  That means that it may or may not have a solution. The method I described easily shows that there is no solution. What else is there to say?

@lulu: thanks. I am actually learning about congruences and linear congruences in elementary number theory, and matrices keep coming into it. My matrix algebra is rusty. Why is a determinant of 5 or -5 a problem mod 10? If you just point me in the direction of the answer, I will research it.

Generally you can reduce to row echelon form (Hermite Normal Form) over any PID or Dedekind domain. There are examples in many prior answers.

The matrix is $
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2  \
3 & 1 \
\end{pmatrix}
$  which has determinant $-5$.

@lulu, is 5 or -5 a problem because they divide into the modulus of 10? I.e., 5 and 10 are not coprime?

Yes.  $5$ is not invertible $\pmod {10}$.  Again, though, all that proves is that some desired values will be unrealizable.  Doesn't tell us which ones.  That's why I just tried to solve the system, and hit a contradiction.

I should have asked how to tell if there is NO solution to a system of modular linear equations. LInear congruences have criteria to determine if and how many solutions there are. I would guess that it would also be true for systems of modular linear equations.
